# Package 'npm' has no installation candidate

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, debian, npm-install

I want to install npm in Debian 9.
I've tried:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

completely installed and `nodejs -v` results: `v4.8.2`.
but when try to run npm an error says:

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

Base on my searches I've tried other ways:
based on this guide: https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-nodejs-ubuntu-17395 I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

results:

```
E: Package 'npm' has no installation candidate
```

Based on another guide I've tried:

```
wget https://npmjs.org/install.sh 
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

results:

```
npm cannot be installed without node.js.
```

of course I've installed nodejs.  I also tried this way:

```
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

It says:

```
nodejs is already the newest version (4.8.2~dfsg-1).
```

What should I do?

Comment: Node comes with npm installed so you should have a version of npm. Can you try npm -v ? Im pretty sure is should be there already, if you not delete it.

Comment: I've mentioned it in my question: bash: npm: command not found. I didn't delete it, I just installed nodejs the way I've described

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the old version

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Install the new version:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Alternatively, for Node.js 9:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[Source](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

It might tell you that you are missing package gnupg2, just install it.